# Ruby: How to allow only a certain kind of objects to be added to a set

Tags: ruby, types, set, enumerable

I'd like to create a Set that only allows a certain kind of (`kind_of?`) objects to be added and an exception to be raised on the attempt to add an alien object.

I haven't found any resources yet and before I start messing around with the ruby core classes I'd be grateful for any advice how to achieve this in an "unobtrusive" manner.

Addition: My goal actually is to create a "templated" container class much like in C++ (e.g. Set) so that I can set the type once at definition of an instance and compare two sets on a class level if they are the same (i.e accept the same type) but keeping interoperability with "default" Sets, as an example `set_instance_a.class == set_instance_b.class` should yield true if they accept the same type of object.

An idea I had was to overload the `::[]` operator so that I could write something like `my_set = MySet[Foo]` which should return a `MySet` instance that only accepts objects of type `Foo`

Thanks!

Comment: So you really want a class builder that lets you say `c = MySet.new(String)` to get a `Set` subclass `c` that only allows you to add `String`s?

Comment: yes, I have some 'model like' class which contains attributes and  collections of objects which are later serialized to JSON. A 'selective set' allows me to define a Set attribute on the model which is only allowed to hold Strings or some other type of object. I think it's not that far fetched to make a container class selective on what it can contain and what not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Class`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Class.html) is an object too so you can create new classes at runtime as needed. The `Class` constructor allows you to specify the base class and even evaluate code within the context of the new class:

> **new(super_class=Object) → a_class**
>   **new(super_class=Object) { |mod| ... } → a_class**
>
> Creates a new anonymous (unnamed) class with the given superclass (or `Object` if no parameter is given). You can give a class a name by assigning the class object to a constant.
>
> If a block is given, it is passed the class object, and the block is evaluated in the context of this class using `class_eval`.

[`class_eval`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-class_eval) lets you define methods and aliases. All this means that you can say things like this:

```
module Kernel
  def MySet(c)
    Class.new(Set) do
      @@allowed = c
      def add(o)
        raise ArgumentError.new("#{o.class} is stinky!") if(!o.is_a?(@@allowed))
        super(o)
      end
      alias_method :<<, :add
    end
  end
end
```

And then:

```
s = MySet(String).new
s.add(6)        # Exception!
s << 'pancakes' # Allowed
```

I patched the `MySet` method into `Kernel` to be consistent with the `Array`, `Complex`, ... methods-that-pretend-to-be-functions, you can put it anywhere you'd like.

Answer (score 3):

```
require "set"

class MySet < Set
  def add e
    raise "Invalid element #{e}" unless e.kind_of?(Foo)
    super(e)
  end
end
```

or, if you do not want to use a subclass, then:

```
require "set"

class Set
  alias original_add :add
  def add e
    raise "Invalid element #{e}" unless e.kind_of?(Foo)
    original_add(e)
  end
end
```

**Edit added in 2017**
To do it without subclassing in a modern way,

```
require "set"

module MySet
  def add e
    raise "Invalid element #{e}" unless e.kind_of?(Foo)
    super(e)
  end
end

class Set
  prepend MySet
end
```

Comment: many thanks! I also needed to overload the `<<` operator since it doesn't use `add` :)

Comment: sorry that I didn't mention it in the original question: My goal actually is to create a "templated" container class (like Set<Foo> in C++). So that I can Set the type it accepts once and then compare two Sets on a class level if they are the "same" (i.e accept the same type) but still keep interoperability with "standard" sets.